# Adding a new <select> to a table row using Jquery, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LRRT.png)

I am new to this web designing, and I would like to put a button which can put a new row on the table. It works, but when tried adding a `<select>` tag in as well, but I don't know enough knowledge to do so. It seems that `type='select'` is absolutely wrong.
So how can i put a `<select>` tag to the new row instead of just text?

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
  $('tr').find('input').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#nmr' + i).html("<td>" + (i + 1) 
 + "</td><td><input type='select' name='shiftid" + i 
 + "'class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='select' name='breakid" + i 
 + "</td><td><input type='number' name='naturasa" + i 
 + "'class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='number' name='naturapu" + i 
 + "'class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='number' name='makannorm" + i
 + "'class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><input type='number' name='ttal" + i
 + "'class='form-control input-md'/></td>");

    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="nmr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    i++;
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="datatable" class="container">
  <h2>Data Input</h2>            
  <table class="table table-condensed" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Shift</th>
        <th>Jam Istirahat</th>
  <th>Natura Sakit</th>
  <th>Natura Puasa</th>
  <th>Makan Normal</th>
  <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="nmr0">
        <td>
   1
  </td>
        <td>
   <select name="shiftid" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled="disabled" value="">-Select An Option-</option>
    <option value="NormalShift">Normal Shift</option>
    <option value="Long Shift">Long Shift</option>
   </select>
  </td>
        <td>
   <select name="breakid" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled="disabled" value="">-Select An Option-</option>
    <option value="break1">11.45-12.15</option>
    <option value="break2">20.30-21.00</option>
    <option value="break3">18.00-18.45</option>
    <option value="break4">00.00-00.30</option>
    <option value="break5">07.00-07.30</option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="nomore" type="number" min="0" name="naturasa" class="form-control">
  </td>
        <td>
   <input id="nomore" type="number" min="0" name="naturapu" class="form-control">
  </td>
        <td>
   <input id="nomore" type="number" min="0" name="makannorm" class="form-control">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="nomore" type="number" min="0" name="ttal" class="form-control">
  </td>
      </tr>
   <tr id='nmr1'></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table><p></p>
  <input type="submit" id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" value="Add Order">
  <input type="submit" id="removedata" value="Remove Order">
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your question and make a jsfiddle

Comment: Your question is not too clear. Mention clearly what result you are expecting. Adding a jsfiddle or working script will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all **#id must be unique, there are no exceptions to this rule.** The four `<input>` all have the same `<input id=`"<del>nomore</del>"...`>`. They have been reassigned as `id="A0"`, `id="B0"`, `id="C0"`, `id="D0"`.
- Replaced `.html(...` with a plain JavaScript method: **[`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)** which does the same thing as `.html()` except it inserts instead of overwriting.
- Removed unnecessary empty `<tr>`
- Moved `i++` which increments before the row is added
- Used **[Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** for the string which makes the process a lot easier (note you don't have to add a ton of `+` at every newline)
- Note `$('tbody')[0]` the bracket notation dereferences the jQuery Object to use a plain JavaScript method on it (i.e. `insertAdjacentHTML()`)
- The correct HTML for a `<select>` is added as well as the proper interpolation of the incremented `i` variable

### Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      var i = 0;
      $("#add_row").click(function() {
            i++;
            $('tbody')[0].insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `      
            <tr id="nmr${i}">
        <td>${i+1}</td>
        <td>
   <select name="shiftid" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled value="">
        -Select An Option-
        </option>
    <option value="Normal Shift">Normal Shift
        </option>
    <option value="Long Shift">
        Long Shift
        </option>
   </select>
  </td>
        <td>
   <select name="breakid" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled value="">
        -Select An Option-
        </option>
    <option value="break1">
        11.45-12.15
        </option>
    <option value="break2">
        20.30-21.00
        </option>
    <option value="break3">
        18.00-18.45
        </option>
    <option value="break4">
        00.00-00.30
        </option>
    <option value="break5">
        07.00-07.30
        </option>
   </select>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="A${i}" type="number" min="0" name="naturasa" class="form-control">
  </td>
        <td>
   <input id="B${i}" type="number" min="0" name="naturapu" class="form-control">
  </td>
        <td>
   <input id="C${i}" type="number" min="0" name="makannorm" class="form-control">
  </td>
  <td>
   <input id="D${i}" type="number" min="0" name="ttal" class="form-control">
  </td>
      </tr>`);
      });
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="datatable" class="container">
  <h2>Data Input</h2>
  <table class="table table-condensed" id="tab_logic">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Shift</th>
        <th>Jam Istirahat</th>
        <th>Natura Sakit</th>
        <th>Natura Puasa</th>
        <th>Makan Normal</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id="nmr0">
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="shiftid" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled value="">-Select An Option-</option>
    <option value="Normal Shift">Normal Shift</option>
    <option value="Long Shift">Long Shift</option>
   </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="breakid" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled value="">-Select An Option-</option>
    <option value="break1">11.45-12.15</option>
    <option value="break2">20.30-21.00</option>
    <option value="break3">18.00-18.45</option>
    <option value="break4">00.00-00.30</option>
    <option value="break5">07.00-07.30</option>
   </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="A0" type="number" min="0" name="naturasa" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="B0" type="number" min="0" name="naturapu" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="C0" type="number" min="0" name="makannorm" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id="D0" type="number" min="0" name="ttal" class="form-control">
        </td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <p></p>
  <input type="submit" id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-left" value="Add Order">
  <input type="submit" id="removedata" value="Remove Order">
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for very detail information, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 3):

you can use [jquery clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy the first table row and then append it to bottom of the table.

you can find last row of the table by using

```
 var $lastTr = $('.classoftable tr').eq(1);
```

and then clone this last row of the table by using

```
 var $clone = $lastTr.clone();
```

and now append this cloned row to your table by using

```
 $clone.appendTo('.classoftable');
```

you can also highlight newly added row by using

```
 $clone.effect("highlight", {
            color: "#3c8dbc"
        }, 2000);
```

for reference use this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/LAECx/)

Comment: yes i already do that, the problem is when i decide to change instead of using input=text, i put a <select>, but the new row didnt display it as a <select>

Comment: i think select tag will not affect your result can see that at http://jsfiddle.net/Tp7hg/